# Adding Microsoft 365 package to Xamarin Studio

Tags: api, xamarin, package, nuget, office365

I'm trying to add 'Microsoft Office 365 Mail, Calendar and Contact Library' package to a project on Xamarin Studio for OSx and get the error :

```
Adding Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices...
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.OData.Client (≥ 6.8.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.OData.Core (= 6.9.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Spatial (= 6.9.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.OData.Edm (= 6.9.0)'.
Downloading Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices 1.0.22...
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

All of the dependencies listed above are installed and other Microsoft packages such as 'Microsoft Authentication Library' were installed successfully.

Any solutions would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Can you look in the Xamarin Studio logs to see what the full stack track is for the null reference? The logs can be found if you select Open Log Directory from the Help menu.

Comment: This is the first line of many: 
`ERROR [2015-01-15 09:05:27Z]: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at System.IO.Packaging.Package.LoadRelationships ()     [0x001e9] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-3.12.0-branch-32/bockbuild-mono-3.12.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.12.0/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.IO.Packaging/Package.cs:338 `

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with Mono failing to resolve the portable library folder which is using %2B instead of +

```
portable-net40%2Bsl5%2Bwp8%2Bwin8%2BMonoAndroid10%2BMonoTouch10%2BWindowsPhoneApp81
```

The NuGet package works fine with Xamarin Studio on Windows.

There is a similar problem with Mono.Data.Sqlite.Portable 1.0.33 where it was using %2BXamarinMac which seemed to be incorrectly being resolved to a part in the zip file. To fix the Mono.Data.Sqlite.Portable NuGet package the Xamarin frameworks were removed from the portable library folder inside the NuGet package and that fixed the problem. I suspect it could be fixed by changing the %2B to + in the NuGet package.

Comment: Thanks, didn't get to try changing the %2B in the package. I've now switched to native development for iOS and android as the Office SDK's for this are easily implemented and just as easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Microsoft Graph.